Custom handler for FastAPI to handle to closure of connections
I have a weird issue with FastAPI. The background story is that I have a queue that consist of jobs that get added when I do a request to a FastAPI endpoint. I am using this to test stuff, so I am intentionally keeping the request open until the job is done by the queue. As there might be a lot of jobs stacking up I want to cancel all of this gracefully when shutting down the application. I have a function to immediately serve all of the open requests who still wait for their response. However, I cannot trigger this using the FastAPI shutdown event in its lifespan. This only get executed when all of the connections are closed and that is exactly what I am trying to do here. So, I tried to register my custom shutdown mechanism which immediately fills all open requests to close them by adding this to the lifespan:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(instance: Starlette):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda signum, frame: handle_shutdown())
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda signum, frame: handle_shutdown())
    logger.info("Startup event executed, signal handlers registered.")
    yield 

This works fine but now FastAPI does not execute its own shutdown mechanism. Any ideas of how I could fix that? I'd appreciate any tips or references.

(This is too long for a comment and too speculative for an answer)
I guess FastApi might have its own signal handlers and by installing your own the original ones are now not called.
To handle a signal in asyncio I recommend:

Do not directly execute a function to handle the situation. Schedule it instead. Or only set a flag.
Call the saved original handler (if any). All handler for a particular signal should form a chain that we don't want to break.

def myhandler(signo, frame):
    call_soon = asyncio.get_running_loop().call_soon_threadsafe
    call_soon(print, "interrupted by signal")  # example, logging preferred
    call_soon(handle_this_interrupt)
    if callable(saved_handler):
        saved_handler(signo, frame)

# to install:

    saved_handler = signal.getsignal(signo)
    signal.signal(signo, myhandler)

# to remove:

    signal.signal(signo, saved_handler)


